# не устанавливается библиотека scrapy в Windows

Tags: python, scrapy

при вводе pip install scrapy

```
Failed  building wheel for Twisted
```

а так же, в конце командной строки ошибка на скрине ниже

[image: лог командной строки]

В чем может быть причина?

версия python 3.6.3

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил вопрос, паралельно установил 2.7 версию, в корневой каталог диска С.
Далее через функцию pip install <имя пакетов> -t lib установил все необходимые библиотеки. После в PyCharm выбрал интерпретатор 2.7 создав внутренними средстами виртуальное окружение. Далее были проблемы с пакетом Interface необходимым для запуска, проблема заключалась в неправильной распаковке, файлы распоквывались zope-> interface -> files
а надо было zope -> files, решил копированием файлов в папку zope из папки interface.

Answer (score 1):

В инструкции по установке написано:
Python 3 is not supported on Windows. This is because Scrapy core requirement Twisted does not support Python 3 on Windows.
https://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.1/intro/install.html

Т.е scrappy для Python 3 не поддерживается на Windows.
Используйте 2.7 или ищите решение без этого модуля.
Ну или ставьте Linux!

Comment: спасиб за ответ, но дело в том, что на ноуте у меня стоит линукс, и там тоже не ставится скрапи

Comment: @AndreyPorkov: тогда задайте отдельный вопрос именно о linux и приведите точную ошибку, которую получаете. Попробуйте, [вот эту инструкцию для установки](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.1/topics/ubuntu.html#topics-ubuntu)

Comment: @jfs: 
Traceback (most_recent_call last) File "/usr/lib/python.py, line 2, in <module> import scrapy Import error: bad magic number in 'scrapy': b'\x03\xf3\r\n' вот, пробовал запускать файл с дериктории питона, куда установился скрапи я не знаю, через консоль пытался найти но на команду scrapy view он не реагирует

Comment: @AndreyPorkov удали *.pyc файл скрипта где делаешь импорт. Выглядит так будто ты до этого пытался с другой версией Python запустить этот скрипт. Нашёл тут https://teamtreehouse.com/community/importerror-bad-magic-number-in-time-bx03xf3rn

Comment: @AndreyPorkov не нужно вопросы в комментарии задавать. *"задайте отдельный [Stack Overflow] вопрос"* [ask]

Comment: @jfs: 
да, но насколько я понял смысл, создание вопросов мембером ограничено технически, а я не горю желанием вести мультиаккаунт.

Comment: @AndreyPorkov: вы хотите сказать, что вы попробовали нажать кнопку ["Задать вопрос"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) и система вам запретила?

Comment: jfs: нет, я прочитал ранее, но не пробовал. Как сменить интерпретатор питона с 3.5 на 2.7 на линуксе?